# Check if element in list of lists contains another list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, function, contains

I have `List` of `Lists` or `arrays`. It contains certain ordered sequences:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6
23 24 25 28
```

etc.

I want to add another sequence, but only if it's unique (easy) and any of the `Lists` does not contain it. So for example:

```
0 1 2
```

will be rejected, and function will return `false`, and

```
9 10
```

will be accepted, and function will return `true`.

Comment: You need to make a start on this, we are not a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you kind stranger! Problem solved.

Comment: I didn't mark it as duplicate, but that duplicate link either answers your question or you haven't explained yourself correctly.

Comment: Maybe at least show your sample data as `List<List<int>>` and `List<int>`, and show what you've attempted that's not working.

Comment: What if only some of the members of the list exist in another list (i.e. `{0, 1, 2, 9, 10}`) ? Do you just want to add the unique numbers as a new list (`{9, 10}`), or all of them? Please provide more information.

Comment: What do you mean by. *"but only if it's unique"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to search through all the lists in a `List<List<int>>` to see if any contain a set of numbers, and if none do, then add the numbers as a new list.

One way to do this is using Linq:

```
public static void AddListIfNotExist(List<List<int>> lists, List<int> newList)
{
    if (lists == null || newList == null) return;

    if (!lists.Any(list => newList.All(item => list.Contains(item))))
    {
        lists.Add(newList);
    }
}
```

In use it might look like:

```
var lists = new List<List<int>> 
{
    new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 },
    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 },
    new List<int> { 23, 24, 25, 28 }
};

var newList1 = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
var newList2 = new List<int> { 9, 10 };

AddListIfNotExist(lists, newList1);
AddListIfNotExist(lists, newList2);
```